# How to check in timber if user is loggedin?

Tags: login

How to check if there is a user is loggedin? Normaly you do this like:

`if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { // do something }`

but how you do this within a Timber template? some thing like?:

`{% if userloggedin %} //do somthing {% endif %}`

Comment: I am not familiar with Timber but can't you pass a boolean variable inside your template? Like `$context['userLoggedIn'] = is_user_logged_in(); Timber::render('index.twig', $context);`

Comment: Also a good idea. The benefit of the user object is that all user related stuff is available

Comment: I agree, it is better to use the user object. I don't know how Timber works so I didn't know the existence of user object :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it already, to do this you can use the 'user' object:

`{% if user %}
 Hello {{ user.user_nicename }}
{% else %}
 you are not loggedin
{% endif %}`

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate, an alternative is:

```
{% if function( 'is_user_logged_in') %}
 - your logged in code here
{% endif %}
```